# NavigationView disappears in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Why does my `NavigationView` disappear when rotating my device to portrait mode. I've already enabled all orientations for my app.

[image]

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct Stocks: Identifiable{
    var id  = UUID()
    var name = String()
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let stocks: [Stocks] = [
        Stocks(name: "Agricultural Bank of China"),
        Stocks(name: "China Communications Construction"),
        Stocks(name: "China Communications Construction Company Limited"),
        Stocks(name: "China Merchants Shekou Industrial Zone Holdings"),
        Stocks(name: "China Railway Construction Corporation Limited"),
        Stocks(name: "China State Construction Engineering Corporation "),
        Stocks(name: "Daqin Railway Company Limited"),
        Stocks(name: "Guotai Junan Securities"),
        Stocks(name: "Huaneng Power International"),
        Stocks(name: "Industrial and Commercial Bank of China"),
        Stocks(name: "Jiangsu Yanghe Brewery"),
        Stocks(name: "Kweichow Moutai"),
        Stocks(name: "Ping An Bank"),
        Stocks(name: "Shanghai International Port Group"),
        Stocks(name: "Shanghai Pudong Development Bank"),
        Stocks(name: "Wuliangye Yibin Company Limited")]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(stocks) {stock in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text(stock.name).font(.title)
                    }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("FTSE China A50 Index"))
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you rotate the iPad into portrait mode, it hides the left pane, which can be shown again by swiping from the left edge. I haven't found any way to prevent this from automatically hiding. You can see what's going on a little more clearly if you modify your code slightly:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(stocks) {stock in
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                NavigationLink(stock.name, destination: Text(stock.name)).font(.title)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("FTSE China A50 Index"))
    }
}
```

Now if you click on a row, you'll see it in the detail pane on the right, and you'll notice that it is shown if you rotate to portrait.

Comment: Very good answer, including how to use the swipe gesture. I'm **not** a fan of how iOS 13 (including iPadOS 13) simply expects experienced users to simply swipe the screen for these kinds of things. At least they gave us a way to add a dismiss button on alerts - but thank you *very* much for confirming that there's no way to get around this. It's rather jarring to set up a master/detail NavigationView with no detail and in iPad portrait you get a blank screen....